# How to display json object using *ngFor in Angular 2 (Data fetch from Firebase)

Tags: angular, angular2-services, ngfor

I want to display the below data from Firebase. When I'm doing {{ response | json }}. It will display following output.

```
<p> Response: {{ response | json }} </p>
```

[image]

```
<ul *ngFor="#value of response.data">
    <li>Value: {{ value.duration }}</li>
</ul>
```

This *ngFor did not work. Please help me.

Comment: What version of Angular 2 are you using `#` is old syntax, we use `let` now :)

Comment: also note that data is not an array...

Comment: I'm using old version of Angular 2. So, # is fine. Yes, data is not in array. It is in Json.